# Remove validation from city field in checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, validation, form-validation

How can I remove the validation from city field which says, "Please use letters only (a-z or A-Z) in this field". I have checked the extension files but I can't find anything there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find below mentioned file If they are not already exist within your theme copy the following files from the **base/default** theme to your theme:

```
template/customer/address/edit.phtml
template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

In each of these files, look for the `<input>` that defines the **city** field and remove the required class from the label, remove the required-attribute class from the input and make sure to remove the *.

Comment: Hi, it causes another issue with my dashboard. After implementing the above method,  I can't see order details in admin. Customer names disappeared. here it is [link](http://s32.postimg.org/7i1hvcmgl/dash.jpg)

Comment: I believe that it can't make any issue, Please check your code again and also check errors log file. Or Roll back the  changes and see what happened

Answer (score 0):

1- Remove the required class from following files in your theme folder.

```
checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

<!--<label for="shipping:city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('city') ?></label>-->
<label for="shipping:city"><?php echo $this->__('city') ?></label>
```

also remove classes from input field as-well

```
<?php //echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>
```

2- copy this core class to your local and remove following lines
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php

```
/*if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getcity(), 'NotEmpty')) {
  $this->addError(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the city number.'));
}*/
```

3- Change the attribute is_required in DB

```
update eav_attribute set is_required=0 where attribute_code='city';
```

Note: step three is a dirty hack, correct way would be creating an setup file in your custom extension.